# How to make a has_one associated model show up in class attributes() result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, nested-attributes, rails-activerecord, has-one

Where `Person` `has_one` `Brain`, should I expect `brain` to show up in the **hash returned by** `attributes()` for `Person`?  If so, how to make that happen?

Rails Console output:

```
1.9.3p327 :003 > Person.new.attributes
 => {"id"=>nil, "name"=>nil, "created_at"=>nil, "updated_at"=>nil} 
1.9.3p327 :004 > Brain.new.attributes
 => {"id"=>nil, "weight_kg"=>nil, "created_at"=>nil, "updated_at"=>nil, "person_id"=>nil}
```

The two models are `Person` and `Brain`:

```ruby
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :brain
  attr_accessible :name
  attr_accessible :brain
  attr_accessible :brain_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :brain

end

class Brain < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  attr_accessible :weight_kg
  attr_accessible :person
  attr_accessible :person_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :person
end
```

`person_id` shows up in the attributes for `Brain` because the `brains` table has a `person_id` column.  No such column need exist for the `people` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure it is a good idea to list associations among attributes, but you can get association names like this:

```
association_names = self.class.reflect_on_all_associations.map(&:name)
```

see [doc on reflections](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_all_associations)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't show attributes for brain in person because if you look at the sql table for person .. there is no field for "brain" .. but in the brain table there is person_id.

Good tip from Viktor on how to reflect on associations!